# Excel formula to check similar names and add their ids to new column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to do that third column in excel.

I need a formula that could check the name column and find the ones with the same values then fetch their ids and put them together in the new column

[link to imgur, showing table data below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNPBt.png)

```
+--------+----+------------+
| Jack   |  1 | 1|2|3      |
| Jack   |  2 | 1|2|3      |
| Jack   |  3 | 1|2|3      |
| Emily  |  4 | 4|5        |
| Emily  |  5 | 4|5        |
| John   |  6 | 6|7|8      |
| John   |  7 | 6|7|8      |
| John   |  8 | 6|7|8      |
| Lauren |  9 | 9|10|11|12 |
| Lauren | 10 | 9|10|11|12 |
| Lauren | 11 | 9|10|11|12 |
| Lauren | 12 | 9|10|11|12 |
+--------+----+------------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your experience with whatever you have tried. Then we could offer help. As your questions stands it looks like you are trying to get someone to do your work for you.

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN("|",1,IF(A$1:A$12=A1,B$1:B$12,""))` in `C1` (array entered) or create your own UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you won't able to access TEXTJOIN function, because of excel version issues
You can make your own function for this.  Enjoy !!!

You can get a result like this
[my_solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ8C2.jpg)

As you can see I have used function Lookup_delimited, 
Three arguments of Lookup_delimited are

1. Lookup value
2. Lookup_Range  (Note: Don't choose the entire column, be specific with your lookup range)
3. Results_Range (The values you want to consolidate)

Steps to get this Lookup_delimited,

Step-1> Open your excel file

Step-2> Press Alt+F11  (shortcut for VBA editor)

Step-3> Insert a new module

Step-4> Paste the below code in there

Step-5> Close your VBA editor, save your file as xlsm (Excel macro-enabled workbook)

Step-6> Your worksheet is ready to use the Lookup_delimited functions

Step-7> Use this formula exactly as mentioned above

Try This:

```
Option Explicit
Function Lookup_delimited(L_Value As Variant, L_Range As Range, R_Range As Range) As String


    Dim Stg As String 'Results storage
    Dim StgTmp As String  'Cell value storage
    Dim Rw As Long   'Row
    Dim Cl As Long   'Column

    Const StgDelimiter = " | "


    Stg = StgDelimiter
    For Rw = 1 To L_Range.Rows.Count
        For Cl = 1 To L_Range.Columns.Count
            If L_Range.Cells(Rw, Cl).Value = L_Value Then


                StgTmp = R_Range.Offset(Rw - 1, Cl - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
                If InStr(1, Stg, StgDelimiter & StgTmp & StgDelimiter) = 0 Then
                    Stg = Stg & StgTmp & StgDelimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next


    Lookup_delimited = Stg 'Return to function


End Function
```

Comment: The function for this is called `TEXTJOIN` however, it came with newer versions of Excel

Comment: Thank you sumit!! worked like a charm. Thank you JvdV as well you guys rock!! I've been working on this for hours